# C# MVC: What are the real advantages to using Modelbinders?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm wondering what the real measurable advantage to using Modelbinders is?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than getting primitives sent into your action:

```
public ActionResult Search(string tagName, int numberOfResults)
```

you get a custom object:

```
public ActionResult Search(TagSearch tagSearch)
```

This makes your Search action "thinner" (a good thing), much more testable and reduces maintenance.

Comment: Did you get the two examples switched around?

Answer (score 0):

> **Model Binders**
>
> A model binder in MVC provides a
>   simple way to map posted form values
>   to a .NET Framework type and pass the
>   type to an action method as a
>   parameter. Binders also give you
>   control over the deserialization of
>   types that are passed to action
>   methods. Model binders are like type
>   converters, because they can convert
>   HTTP requests into objects that are
>   passed to an action method. However,
>   they also have information about the
>   current controller context.

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410405.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Here's another benefit:

You can create modelbinders that retrieves an object from the database just given an ID.

This will allow you to get actions like this

```
// GET /Orders/Edit/2
public ActionResult Edit(Order order){
  return View(order);
}
```

And the custom `ModelBinder` would do the datafetching for you, keeping your controller skinny.

Without that `ModelBinder` it could look like this:

```
// GET /Orders/Edit/2
public ActionResult Edit(int id){
  var order = _orderRepository.Get(id);
  // check that order is not null and throw the appropriate exception etc
  return View(order);
}
```